# Handle multiple Intent Services within the same class (Receive data back from multiple services)

Tags: android, intentservice, receiver

I have initialized 2 public Receiver variable at beginning of my register.class

```
public RegisterReceiver rReceiver;
public ConvertAddressToLatLongReceiver catllReceiver;
```

and then in onCreate() I defined them as follows

```
rReceiver = new RegisterReceiver(new Handler());
rReceiver.setReceiver(this);

catllReceiver = new ConvertAddressToLatLongReceiver(new Handler());
catllReceiver.setReceiver(this);
```

Both of these Receivers implement onReceiveResult() at the end of the class. Is there a way to distinguish which of the services is calling the onReceiveResult() fucntion like distinguishing between which buttons are clicked in onClick() ?

Edited:
this is one of my Receiver classes.

```
import ca.amoh.track.trackingnetwork.interfaces.Receiver;


    public class RegisterReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    private Receiver rReceiver;

    public RegisterReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    public void setReceiver(RegisterScreen rReceiver) {
        this.rReceiver = rReceiver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (rReceiver != null) {
            rReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `resultCode` parameter or otherwise put some marker info in the `Bundle` parameter. Is both the receiver your private classes or part of some library? It's bit difficult to understand as you have not put the origin of these Receiver classes.

Comment: Is `ResultReceiver` and `ConvertAddressToLatLongReceiver` are `BroadcastReceiver`?? If yes then suggestion in my last comment won't work.

Comment: A marker info in the bundle will work great! And yea my receiver classes are private classes that extends ResultReceiver.

Comment: Ok. I have put same in answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the structure of the `onReceiveResult` method:

```
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
}
```

Now you can either use the `resultCode` parameter to distinguish between two results or use the `Bundle` parameter with some marker information.

**Edit**

If you use the `resultCode` then it is slightly easy to switch between results:

```
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    switch(resultCode){
        case 100: \\ result from one receiver
             ...                 
        case 200: \\ result from another receiver
             ...
    }
}
```